# Is there a built in way of converting Option to a scalaz validation?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I've been looking but I can't find an implicit converter.  Obviously it would be trivial to write one but I'm wondering if I've missed one in the scalaz library somehow!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scalaz has a implicit conversion of `Option` to [**`OptionW`**](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.2/doc/index.html#scalaz.OptionW), which declares the `toFailure` and `toSuccess` methods.

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example? I tried this with both scalaz._ and Scalaz._ imported, and I still get "error: value toValidationNel is not a member of Option"

Comment: Doesn't OptionOps convert for you?

Comment: `toValidationNel` is a method usable on validation, not on option.

Comment: ```import scalaz.syntax.std.option._; 
myOption.toSuccessNel(myError)```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have methods that transform "Some" into the "happy path" (in case of Validation -> Success, in case of Disjunction \/-) and then you need to define an error description for the None.

I use this when I receive an Optional parameter and I want to raise an error if is not provided.

Example:

```
scala> import scalaz.Scalaz._
import scalaz.Scalaz._

scala> import scalaz._
import scalaz._

scala> Some("clientId123").toSuccessNel("Client id is mandatory")
res0: scalaz.ValidationNel[String,String] = Success(clientId123)

scala> None.toSuccessNel("Client id is mandatory")
res1: scalaz.ValidationNel[String,Nothing] = Failure(NonEmpty[Client id is mandatory])
```

If you accumulate the errors using applicatives you can give a comprehensive error message to the final user, something like:

```
Client id is mandatory, country is mandatory, etc
```